# "marshrutkas" tag wrongly written

Tags: discussion, tag-renaming

As I was just looking for a marshrutka in Ukraine in noticed the tag:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marshrutkas

It's a Russian word commonly used in all countries of the former Soviet Union with no equivalent in English. I would suggest to use the Russian plural (which is suitable for most Slavic languages) instead of a weird arbitrary English plural.

Marshrutk*i* instead of Marshrutka*s*

Or if there is no agreement on that the singular should do it: Marshrutka

Comment: "weird arbitrary English plural" - it's actually a completely standard English plural: take the word, add -s. [English generally doesn't care about other languages' pluralisations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351980)...

Comment: @AakashM - that's part of the problem.

Comment: You might not like how English works, but there's no point arguing with it, it just doesn't listen.

Answer (score 4):

I think a better approach is possible here - using a proper English name instead. I've created the tag [shared-taxis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shared-taxis) and made tag [marshrutkas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marshrutkas) it's synonym. This way we can also reuse the same tag for questions about similar forms of transportation in other countries, as currently this tag only has 7 questions.

Comment: Marshrutkas are not exactly the same as shared taxis. For instance, Kyrgyz refer to Marshrutkas as some sort of Mercedes-Minibus that is going a specific route, while Uzbeks consider any kind of vehicle that goes somewhere with several passengers as Marshrutka. It seems in Ukraine it's basically a bus. "Shared Taxis" itself are mostly the Israeli "Sherut". Anyway, if you mention "Marshrutka" in the correct context people know what is meant

Comment: @Qohelet I agree that there isn't a precise definition of what a "marshrutka" is, but I think that "shared taxi" should cover all types of them.

Comment: @Qohelet for an exhaustive list, see Wikipedia's article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_taxi

Answer (score -1):

As per [this comment](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/marshrutkas-tag-wrongly-written#comment15256_6455) I suggest creating the tag [kyrgyz-marshrutkas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyrgyz-marshrutkas) else I'd like to see all airline tags merged into [airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airlines).